# Rotate an element with constraints

Tags: javascript

So as the title suggests I am rotating an element, nothing special. To do so I am using the [PointerEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent). I do calculate an offset and update an initial value for the degree to make sure that the element does not jump on consecutive user actions, e.g. when you let loose of the element and start to rotate over again.
What I am struggling with is to add a few constraints. For example I would want to make sure that:

- If `N` is pointing to north, allow only counter clockwise rotation.
- Only if `N` is not pointing to north allow rotation in both directions until `N` is pointing to north.
- Overall allow only one full turn.

The problem is  not so much to set up the conditions for those constraints but rather that they do not seem to be working consistently while the `pointermove` event is being triggered.
For example for the first rule I did try to do something like this:

```
if (currentDegree + initialDegree - offsetDegree <= 0) {
  box.style.transform = `rotate(${
    currentDegree + initialDegree - offsetDegree
  }deg)`;
}
```

This does somewhat work but if I only move the pointer fast enough I can easily overcome the restriction. Sometimes the element even stops before `N` is pointing to north, so I am wondering if that is even the right approach to the problem.
I am posting a fiddle with no constraints so you can get an idea on what I am trying to do.
I would appreciate any advice, but suggesting a library which would help me to implement those rules is not what I need. Thanks in advance.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const { x, y, width } = box.getBoundingClientRect();
let boxCenter = width / 2;
let boxXPos = x;
let boxYPos = y;
let initialDegree = 0;
let offsetDegree = 0;
let currentDegree = 0;

function calcDegree(x, y) {
  const degree = Math.floor(Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI) + 90);
  return degree < 0 ? 360 + degree : degree;
}

function onPointerMove(event) {
  const x = event.clientX - boxXPos - boxCenter;
  const y = event.clientY - boxYPos - boxCenter;
  currentDegree = calcDegree(x, y);

  box.style.transform = `rotate(${
    currentDegree + initialDegree - offsetDegree
  }deg)`;
}

box.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {
  box.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
  const x = event.clientX - boxXPos - boxCenter;
  const y = event.clientY - boxYPos - boxCenter;
  offsetDegree = calcDegree(x, y);

  box.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove);
  box.addEventListener(
    'pointerup',
    () => {
      initialDegree += currentDegree - offsetDegree;
      box.removeEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove);
    },
    { once: true }
  );
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const { x, y } = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  boxXPos = x;
  boxYPos = y;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#app {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: inherit;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbd6b8;
  border: 1px solid #94af9f;
  cursor: move;
}

.direction {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.north {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.east {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.south {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.west {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="direction north">N</div>
    <div class="direction east">E</div>
    <div class="direction south">S</div>
    <div class="direction west">W</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the angle of "North" to -360 and 0 degrees (clamping). This is negative because you want to allow a counter clockwise move from the initial position, which is a moving in negative direction. If it were clockwise, the range would have to be [0, 360].

To know which way to update the current angle, you could check the difference that the last pointer move made and interpret a difference of less than 180 degrees as a clockwise move, and anything else a counter clockwise move. This will determine how the current angle should be updated (by increasing it or decreasing it). This means that angle could exceed the range we want to stay within, i.e. [-360, 0]. If that gets exceeded, you would need to re-calibrate the global variable(s) that are involved.

To help myself understand the meaning of the global variables involved, I named one `pointerToNorthDegree`, which is the angle between the location of "North" and the Pointer. This angle is to remain constant when the users drags the pointer (because North will move accordingly). Only when there is an overrun, this angle needs to be updated without moving North.

There was one doubt I had: if the user makes a full counter clockwise turn, putting North again at the top, releases the pointer, and then wants to repeat that operation again, would they still only be allowed to turn counter clock wise, or would they now need to "unwind" and actually move in clockwise direction. The difference is one line of code, which I have marked with a comment.

I added some other comments as well in the updated code below:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const { x, y, width } = box.getBoundingClientRect();
const boxCenter = width / 2;
let boxXPos = x;
let boxYPos = y;
let pointerToNorthDegree; // degrees of where north is relative to where pointer is
let northDegree = 0; // degrees of where north is relative to top

// Map any angle to range 0..359
const mod = ang => ((ang % 360) + 360) % 360;
// Clamp a value between min/max range
const clamp = (value, min, max) => Math.min(max, Math.max(min, value));

const calcDegree = (x, y) => mod(Math.floor(Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI) + 90));

const getPos = (e) => [e.clientX - boxXPos - boxCenter, e.clientY - boxYPos - boxCenter];

function onPointerMove(event) {
  const pointerDegree = calcDegree(...getPos(event)); 
  // Calculate a relative angle change in the range -180..179, 
  //   and determine where north should be. It will get an 
  //   angle that might exceed 0..359 range, which can be used to
  //   detect an overrun:
  northDegree += mod(pointerDegree + pointerToNorthDegree - northDegree + 180) - 180;
  // Should not rotate beyond home position in either direction:
  const clampedNorthDegree = clamp(northDegree, -360, 0); // This range allows a full CCW turn from 0 degrees
  if (northDegree != clampedNorthDegree) {
    // If cursor was moving further than allowed, then use the current degree 
    //    as the new offset, so that if the cursor moves in the opposite 
    //    direction, rotation will happen immediately from that reference onwards.
    northDegree = clampedNorthDegree;
    pointerToNorthDegree = northDegree - pointerDegree;
  }
  box.style.transform = `rotate(${northDegree}deg)`;
}

box.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {
  const pointerDegree = calcDegree(...getPos(event));
  // Remove next line if you don't want to allow another CCW turn from the home position 
  //    when the previous operation ended at north via a CCW turn.
  if (northDegree == -360) northDegree = 0;
  pointerToNorthDegree = northDegree - pointerDegree;
  box.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
  box.addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove);
  box.addEventListener('pointerup', () => box.removeEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove));
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => ({ x: boxXPos, y: boxYPos } = box.getBoundingClientRect()));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#app {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: inherit;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbd6b8;
  border: 1px solid #94af9f;
  cursor: move;
}

.direction {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.north {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.east {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.south {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.west {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="direction north">N</div>
    <div class="direction east">E</div>
    <div class="direction south">S</div>
    <div class="direction west">W</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution depends on the pointer location wrt box center. The closer you are to the center, the curvature (dS/dTheta) of your pointer trail will increase, thus you cross quadrants (0-90,90-180,180-270,270-360) very fast and the box will spin erratic. You can certainly fix your code to put proper restraints on these values.

I prefer going stepwise in these kind of tasks. That makes it a bit easier and pixel independent. I also throttled the `mouseover` to 60fps. Replace the mouse event with the pointer ones if you wish.

In the example below you can adjust `dRotMax`, `dRotMin` and `rotStep` inside `resize` event if you wanted to.

```js
!function(){
  const box = document.querySelector('.box');
  let rotStarted = false,
      busy = false,
      prevX = null,
      prevY = null,
      currRot = 360,
      rotStep = 1,
      dRotMax = 10,
      dRotMin = -10;
  window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => rotStarted = true)
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    prevX = null;
    prevY = null;
    rotStarted = false;
  })
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(!rotStarted){return}
    if(busy){return}
    busy = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(()=> busy = false)
    prevX = prevX ?? e.clientX;
    prevY = prevY ?? e.clientY;
    let dX = -prevX + (prevX = e.clientX),
        dY = -prevY + (prevY = e.clientY),
        dRot = Math.max(dRotMin, Math.min(dRotMax, (dX - dY) * rotStep));
    currRot = Math.max(0, Math.min(360, dRot + currRot))
    box.style.transform = `rotate(${currRot}deg)`
    //console.log(dX, dY, dRot)
  })
}()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#app {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: inherit;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbd6b8;
  border: 1px solid #94af9f;
  cursor: move;
}

.direction {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.north {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.east {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.south {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.west {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="direction north">N</div>
    <div class="direction east">E</div>
    <div class="direction south">S</div>
    <div class="direction west">W</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to change how axis control the rotation based on angle quadrants, then convert `rotStep` into a function. The main advantage is we get rid of `getBoundingClientRect` and `atan2` all together.

```js
!function(){
  const box = document.querySelector('.box');
  let rotStarted = false,
      busy = false,
      prevX = null,
      prevY = null,
      currRot = 360,
      epsilon = 10e-1,
      rotStep = (r, axis) => { //0 for x, 1 for y
        let quad = r / 90,
            //at transition points, disable 1 axis to prevent jitter
            isTransition = Math.abs(Math.round(quad) - quad) <= epsilon;
        switch(quad | 0) {
          case 0:
            return 1
          case 1: //3 o'clock, 
            return axis 
              ? 1 
              : isTransition ? 0 : -1
          case 2: //6 o'clock
            return axis 
              ? isTransition ? 0 : -1 
              : -1
          case 3: //9 o'clock
          case 4:
            return axis 
              ? -1 
              : isTransition ? 0 : 1
        }
      },
      dRotMax = 10,
      dRotMin = -10;
  window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => rotStarted = true)
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    prevX = null;
    prevY = null;
    rotStarted = false;
  })
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(!rotStarted){return}
    if(busy){return}
    busy = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(()=> busy = false)
    prevX = prevX ?? e.clientX;
    prevY = prevY ?? e.clientY;
    let dX = -prevX + (prevX = e.clientX),
        dY = -prevY + (prevY = e.clientY),
        dRot = Math.max(dRotMin, Math.min(dRotMax, dX * rotStep(currRot, 0) + dY * rotStep(currRot, 1)));
    currRot = Math.max(0, Math.min(360, dRot + currRot))
    box.style.transform = `rotate(${currRot}deg)`
    //console.log(dX, dY, dRot)
  })
}()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#app {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: inherit;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbd6b8;
  border: 1px solid #94af9f;
  cursor: move;
}

.direction {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.north {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.east {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.south {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.west {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="direction north">N</div>
    <div class="direction east">E</div>
    <div class="direction south">S</div>
    <div class="direction west">W</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually did not have any problem with the box spinning when the pointer came closer to the center to be honest. You did manage to stop the rotation at 0°, but at around 90° the element can not be correctly rotated anymore and dependent on where I place my pointer in your snippet, to begin the rotation, the element is rotating in the wrong direction. Thanks for your answer so far, but it does not really help me with my problem.

Comment: I will try out the throttling and see if that helps.

Comment: What does it mean at 90 degree the element cannot be correctly rotated anymore? What is the desired expectation for rotation around 90 degrees? . Such constraint is nowhere written in the initial 3 constraints you mentioned. With this algo, there is no such thing as depending on where you put the mouse. Dragging on x towards right turns clockwise, dragging downwards in y turns counterclockwise independent of mouse location. This allows one to get rid of both getBoundingClientRect and atan2 which are both expensive. If you want to change the directions make rotStep negative.